Altair layer chart, force x axis and y axis + ticks to be all together
I have a bunch of dataframes that I don't want to merge because they have the same column names, I want them in different series.
So, I make separate charts and put them in a layerchart together at the end.
Sometimes though, the data is such that the chart changes, the x axis will be on the top or bottom, y axis on the left or right, different offsets, different x and y domains. This makes the final layerchart have a ton of axes and it looks horrible. How can I force them to all use one unified axis? resolve_scale='shared' makes them scaled to the same domain and range, but still leaves behind all the copies.
Edit: I've tried resolve_axis() too. I'm confused, it seems like it's forcing independent axes.


From more testing, it seems like this behaviour only happens when I include my last dataframe, which is super weird.

Ok, I fixed this by.... making my last dataframe series have a shorter name. One of the columns just had the series name for the entire column, maybe something with the legend messed this up.
